# Understanding Linear Regression from statistical learning theory lecture

Tags: statistics, expected-value, linear-regression

I was reading Linear Regression. But I am unable to understand why that red-marked term turns out to be zero. Can anybody help me understand that?
TIA

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expectations of conditional expectations are just expectations, e.g.

$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[z|x]] = \mathbb E[z].$$
Also you can always pull out all functions of $x$ out of the conditional distribution given $x$.

Then you can calculate, assuming $(x,y) \sim \mathcal D$

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbb E[(h(x) - g(x))(g(x) - y)] = &\mathbb E[\mathbb E[(h(x) - g(x))(g(x) - y)|x]] \\ = &\mathbb E[(h(x) - g(x))(g(x) - \mathbb E[y|x])] \\ = &\mathbb E[(h(x) - g(x))(g(x) - g(x))] \\
= & 0.\end{aligned}$$